# Linearly independent vectors over a field and its subfield

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields, extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $\mathrm{F}_q$ be a subfield of $\mathrm{F}_{q^m}$. $\mathrm{F}_{q^m}$ can be seen as an $m$-dimensional vector space over $\mathrm{F}_q$. Let $v_1,\ldots, v_k \in \mathrm{F}_{q^m}^n$ be linearly independent over $\mathrm{F}_{q^m}$. So this set spans a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathrm{F}_{q^m}^n$. Clearly this set of vectors are also linearly independent over $\mathrm{F}_q$.

**Question:** How can we make an $mk$-dimensional subspace of $\mathrm{F}_q^n$ out of this set of linearly independent?

**note:** to make the question more specific, we can consider $v_1=u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n$ where $u_1,u_2,\ldots, u_n$ are linearly independent elements in $\mathrm{F}_{q^m}$ ($n\leq m$) and $v_i=(u_1^{q^{i-1}},\ldots,u_n^{q^{i-1}})$ for $1\leq i\leq k$. We already know the set of $n$-vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ with this form are linearly independent over $\mathrm{F}_{q^m}$ and generate a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathrm{F}_{q^m}^n$.

Comment: Do you mean "a $mk$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{F}_q^{nm}$? If yes, a way to do this should be to decompose the $v_i$'s over a $\mathbb{F}_q$-basis of $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$. This is also known as a restriction of scalar, you can work it out on small example over finite fields.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I mean an $mk$ dimension subspace  of $\mathrm{F}_q^n$ not of $\mathrm{F}_q^{nm}$.

Answer (score 0):

**I have this answer to my own question but I am not quite sure:**

Let $a_1,\ldots, a_m$ be a basis of $\mathrm{F}_{q^m}$ over $\mathrm{F}_{q}$. So the vector multiplication $(a_1,\ldots,a_m)^T\times (v_1,\ldots, v_k)=(b_{11},b_{12},\ldots, b_{mk})$ is the basis of our $mk$-dimensional vector space over $\mathrm{F}_q$.

**Is it always true to make an $mk$ linearly independent vectors over $\mathrm{F}_q$ in such a way?**

Comment: I'm afraid I don't entirely understand how to interpret your original question then. There are lots of ways to do what you mention in the comment. Is that what you are asking about? Are you actually trying to construct $\mathbb{F}_{q}$-linear sets? John Sheekey has several papers on MRD codes that contain many lemmas, so I'm not sure which lemma you mean by "Sheekey's lemma".

Comment: How are you ensuring that the $b_{ij}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$? Or even that they are elements of $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{n}$ (if that is what you are considering)? I don't see how to say that without either 1: extra assumptions, or 2: a field reduction map (which will give you a collection of vectors in $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{mn}$ and not $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{n}$).

Comment: Or are you just trying to construct a collection of vectors in $\mathbb{F}_{q^{m}}^{n}$ that are linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$? In this case "basis of our vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$" is probably not the language you intend.

Comment: @MorganRodgers do you have any idea?